# Full-width Images in container with padding

Tags: html, css

I want the images I include on my posts to be full width, but my post container has padding. What can I do to make images fill the padding?

```css
.post {
  padding: 40px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 700px;
}
.post img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Comment: prepare jsfiddle, it would be easier that way. You can remove paddings from post and attach them to child nodes or you can set img to sometihng like: `margin-left:-40px; width: calc(100% + 80px)`, but as I said- jsfiddle and we can start to play

Answer (score 3):

You should compensate with negative margin for the parent padding. However, the trick is to use `box-sizing: border-box;` on the parent, so you don't have to use `overflow: hidden` on it to prevent a horizontal scrollbar.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.post {
  padding: 40px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.post img {
  width: calc(100% + 80px);
  position: relative;
  left: -40px;
  top: -40px;
  margin: 0 -80px -40px 0;
  margin-right: -80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg" />
  <div class="content">
    Some content here...
  </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: the `body { margin: 0;}` is added just to overcome a pesky 10px margin SO snippet adds when small, it is not crucial to the solution itself.

ANOTHER NOTE: I have also removed the `700px` width from `.post` to point the fact that this solution scales responsively. You can add it back and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You should break up your elements more and write CSS for each element's class inside your post container. That way you can have more control over each different kind of content or element in the container.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="post">
    <img src="/foo.png">
    <div class="content">
        <p>All the foo</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Styles**:

```
.post {
    color:#000;
    background-color:#fff;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:700px;
}

.post .content {
    padding: 40px;
}

.post img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: If this is WordPress, as I suspect it is, while your solution works and is technically correct, it is also likely to generate a lot of headacke due to how themes built different templates dynamically in most WP themes.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, that if fair. How can you assume that it is Wordpress with the information provided? The classes he has provided are pretty generic.

Comment: You are right, it was more of a feeling I had in mind from the moment I saw the question than a logical conclusion. No idea why I thought of that, but I did. However, I don't think considering apps these days are templating is a bad thing when trying to find a front-end solution. I didn't mean to speculate and I appologise if you felt I did. It's the scenario I've built when trying to give a good answer to the question.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, no reason to apologize. I was just wondering if you saw something that I did not. An answer that is Wordpress specific could be helpful for users who come across this question in the future.

Comment: My code is so so messy that I can't find a solution. Literally. Thank you SO much for your help though! @MaxBaldwin

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to apply negative margins on the image, so that it overlaps its parent's padding.

In the following snippet, the second child has negative `margin-left` and `margin-right` that match the parent's `padding`:

```html
<div style="padding: 10px; background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 200px">
    <div style="background-color: green; height: 100px"></div>
    <div style="background-color: blue; height: 100px; margin-left: -10px; margin-right: -10px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is going to cause more issues in the long run than it is going to solve. There is really no excuse to use negative margins unless you are doing something with an animation.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin The question was explicitely `What can I do so my images fill the padding?`, therefore I'm assuming here that we have no control on the parent's style.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin, I am very interesed in hearing your arguments on why negative margin is something to avoid in CSS. I am genuinely interested in your point of view on this subject.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, as an experienced developer I can tell you that when you use negative margin or padding you are not fixing the problem, but simply putting a bandage over it. The solution to this issue is not to fill the padding, but to fix the mistakes that have already been made rather than building on top of the mistake. Negative margins and padding have very little acceptable uses. This is not one of them.

Comment: People tend to consider me an experienced frontend developer too, although I keep telling them the only thing I know is how much I don't know. However, if one takes care of the box-sizing of the element that has negative margins (so it doesn't push or pull anything else from around it) I really do not see any buggy or unexpected behaviour. Could you provide an example of unwanted behavior due to negative margins?